# Remove file name extension in footer in Microsoft Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft

I have been doing several Excel projects for a class that I am taking, and the majority of them are requiring that I insert a custom footer with the file name on the left side of some or all sheets in a workbook. However, I want it to display the name of the file, but not the file extension. The only two ways I can think of to use the file name in my footers would be to click the “Insert File Name” button, or manually enter the name of my workbook.

[image: Excel for Mac Custom Footer Dialog]

Is there a way for Excel to be able to automatically insert the file name without including its extension? Thanks!

Comment: Is this the Footer used when printing out the workbook?  I guess you can also view the footer inside the app, but it's very awkward to do so, so I assume this is for printing.  The short answer is "no", the &File macro includes the extension, if you tell the Mac's Finder to hide the extension.  You could remove the extension entirely, something supported in old Mac OS versions and Excel, but not anymore (just tried it).  If this is for printing, I'd suggest using the Sheet name in the footer, and setting the sheet name to be something specific, maybe even (manually) including the base filename

Comment: Thank you for the answer @jimtut! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

The short answer is "no", the `&[File]` macro includes the extension, if you tell the Mac's Finder to hide the extension. In the past you could remove the extension entirely, something supported in old Mac OS versions and Excel, but not anymore (just tried it).

If this is for printing, just use the Sheet name in the footer, and set the sheet name to be something specific, maybe even (manually) including the base filename in the sheet name if you need that in the printout.